# Change UITableViewCell height touch up inside

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, segue, uigesturerecognizer

As the title says, I'd like to make my cells dynamically change height. I try to be as clear that I can. When I touch up inside a cell (prototype cell), the cell change height (from 44 to 88);in the cell there is an UIImage (88px height) partially hidden and where the cell is hidden there is view, touching up starts a segue to a second tableView; when I touch up inside an other cell the previous cell return to 44px height an this other cell change height as the previous one. Follow a scheme of I need to do.

[image]

I think that this is quite difficult, so If someone could help me doing this feature I would be very grateful!! or if you know any examples to get ideas (by gitHub for example) please report me!
thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Couldn't you create a button that takes up the dimensions of the cell, link an action to it that sets the dimensions of the cell and resets the dimensions of any other cell? If you need help with this I can provide an answer.

Comment: @Acoop thanks a lot for your answer! yeah it's not a good idea, but the button dimension should be 44x88, is it appropriate? yeah, go on and thanks you in advance!

Comment: @Acoop sorry I was wrong, there must be two button 44x400, one for to change cell height and the other for to make segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so bad. I have done it like this, there might be smarter ways to do it.
The important stuff is tableView.beginUpdate and ....endUpdate.

```
  //
    //  DynamicTableViewController.swift
    //  DynamicCellTest
    //
    //  Created by Lars Christoffersen on 27/08/15.
    //  Copyright (c) 2015 Lars Christoffersen. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit

    class DynamicTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var dataCource = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
        var extraHeight:CGFloat?
        var selectedRowIndex:Int?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {


            if extraHeight != nil && selectedRowIndex != nil && selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row{
                return 41 + extraHeight!
            }else{
                return 41
            }
        }


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
            extraHeight = 100
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
            extraHeight = 0
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return dataCource.count
        }


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            cell.textLabel?.text = dataCource[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah it works! I had find an other way to do this, but looking how does it work both in your and mine project I'd like to tell you if there were possibile make ALL cell to "normal" height when I scroll the table.